# Does using functional languages help against computing values repeatedly?

Tags: functional-programming

Consider a function f(x,y):

```
f(x,0) = x*x;
f(0,y) = y*(y + 1);
f(x,y) = f(x,y-1) + f(x-1,y);
```

If one tries to implement that recursively in some language like C++ he will encounter a problem.

Suppose the function is first called with `x = x0` and `y = y0`. Then for any pair (x,y) where `0 <= x < x0` and `0 <= y < y0` the intermediate values will be computed multiple times - recursive calls will form a huge tree in which multiple leaves will in fact contain the same pairs (x,y). For pairs (x,y) where x and y are both close to 0 values will be computed numerous times.

For instance, I tested a similar function implemented in C++ - for `x=20` and `y=20` its computation takes about 4 hours (yes, four Earth hours!).

Obviously the implementation can be rewritten in such way that repeated computation doesn't occur - either iteratively or with a cache table.

The question is: will functional languages perform any better and avoid repeated computations when implementing a function like above recursively?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. This is not something that is inherently faster in functional languages. That said, I think it's possible to implement such an optimization in a functional language, but I don't know the specifics so I won't give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term you're looking for here is [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

> In computing, memoization is an
>   optimization technique used primarily
>   to speed up computer programs by
>   having function calls avoid repeating
>   the calculation of results for
>   previously-processed inputs.

No, functional language do not automatically implement memoization. You can implement it in them, but in C++ as well. It is true, however, that when you write purely functional code (i.e. with no side effects), then memoization is easier. Some dynamic languages (Perl, for instance) have auto-memoization modules that can easily memoize any function. There's a discussion of this subject in the [Automatic memoization section of the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#Automatic_memoization).

For example here's a naive C++ Fibonacci:

```
long fib_rec(long index)
{
    if (index < 2)
        return index;
    else
        return fib_rec(index - 1) + fib_rec(index - 2);
}
```

And here's a memoized version:

```
long fib_memoized_aux(vector<long>& cache, long index)
{
    if (cache[index] >= 0)
    return cache[index];

    cache[index] = fib_memoized_aux(cache, index - 1) + fib_memoized_aux(cache, index - 2);
    return cache[index];
}


long fib_memoized(long index)
{
    vector<long> cache(index + 1, -1);
    cache[0] = 0;
    cache[1] = 1;

    return fib_memoized_aux(cache, index);
}
```

Comment: Memoization in turn often raises the subject of hash-consing, because a. hash-consing can be seen as a sort of memoization on the constructors of the hash-consed type b. memoization benefits from having a cheap comparisons for the values of the input type, and that's exactly what hash-consing provides. But in the case of the memoization of a function of integer arguments the point is moot.